# Reverse an Array and assign to new array

Tags: c#, arrays, reverse

Why do I get an error at the following when trying to initialize `arrChar2` to the `Reverse` of `arrChar1` (error is at line `arrChar2` initialization)?:

```
char[] arrChar1 = inputString.ToCharArray();

char[] arrChar2 = arrChar1.Reverse();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you are using the [IEnumerable Reverse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358497%28v=vs.100%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) extensions that returns (in your context) an `IEnumerable<char>` not a char array.
If you want to get an array of chars, as output, you need to be explicit

```
char[] arrChar2 = arrChar1.Reverse().ToArray();
```

Comment: Had to wait 10 min to accept your answer; please don't be the guy who downvoted me bc you though I didn't accept your answer.

Comment: @JeffOrris not me, but don't worry about it. Reps are fun but not the main reason to be here.

Comment: Steve 9 I use to care more..but am baffled at the downvote.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the easiest way, as you don't need to create more variables:

```
using System;

 public class Program
 {
    public static void Main()
    {
        var inputString = "abcd";

        char[] arrChar1 = inputString.ToCharArray();

        Array.Reverse(arrChar1);

        Console.WriteLine(arrChar1);
    }
}
```